# Cannot Edit in read only editor Codesandbox

Tags: github, package.json, codesandbox

I am trying to use codesandbox by importing the github repository.  I am not able to edit the contents of the **package.json** file.  It says **cannot edit in ready only editor**.  How to solve this error?

Answer (score 5):

step1: Ctrl+save

step2: Refresh the webpage from the web browser.

That's it. You are good to go now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't even edit any other files for github repository. You can fork that codesandbox and then edit.
I also met that kind of situation and it worked after fork.

Comment: but why it happens , i wants to know ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just went back to the Dashboard, and re-opened the sandbox. Then I was able to edit it like usual. However, I did notice that the GitHub linkage was gone then.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I created new branch in the editor of the project, then I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Dashboard in CodeSandbox you can re-open your code from there. After opening your code, click on the Github icon. You can see the option to Export to Github, and you can see how many changes you have made. 
But if you open your code from the link on Github you will be in a read-only editor mode.

If this is the first time to open the code in CodeSandbox (for example, you are viewing somebody else's code) then you have to fork it in order to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new branch. Try three dot menu . . . then “Branch from current” on the mobile version.

[image: upper right three dot menu]

[image: branch from current]

Or, I like git in the terminal:

```
git status 
# check for edits to stash or commit

# then create a new branch 
# from current checked out branch

git checkout -b new-branch-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check settings once
File->Preferences-> CodeSandbox Settings-> Editor->Disable VIM extension using toggle switch